# Count of no of files which contain a particular string in its name

Tags: grep, find

I am simply trying to count how many files in a given directory contain a particular string anywhere in its name ( not the total occurance of string ) & ignore hidden directories

Example

```
>> ls -a
.hidden_dir
string1.nfo 
'string1 - string.exe' 
string5-.mkv
```

Here , ignoring the hidden directory , 3 files contain the letter "string" anywhere in their name , so i expect grep to return 3 correctly but its not working & returns 0 instead.
Here's the grep command i am using -

```
grep --exclude-dir=".*" -l "string" * | wc -l
```

Comment: First you state that the file should contain the string, but later it's the name of the file that contains it. That's two different things. Which one are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the name of the file should contain the string , sorry for confusion , edited in question to make it more apparent

Comment: You also need to specify should it recursively append all subdirectories or list just the contents of the current directory. You mention that hidden directories should be ignored, but how about hidden files?

Comment: i should only list the contents of current directory , hidden files should not be ignored

Comment: `ls *string* | wc -l` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pure bash code:

```sh
arr=(*string*) && printf '%d\n' "${#arr[@]}"
```

**Details:**

- `arr=(*string*)`: Find all entries in current directories that have name `string` anywhere and put them into array `arr`
- `printf '%d\n' "${#arr[@]}"`: Print length of array `arr`

---

Based on comments below here is a `find` solution:

```sh
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname '*string*' ! -name '*.txt' \
-exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@//*/.}"' _ {} + | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks for the pure bash solution , its working well for my question although i used grep because i am familiar with it & with all its flags it make it quite flexible .is it possible to ignore a file with any particular extension in this approach ( i meant equivalent of grep --exclude='*.txt'  for ignoring files ) if a grep or find solution is possible , it would be better in terms of flexibility imo

Comment: Don't know why but the bash solution is correctly printing 3 as output but find command outputs 2

Comment: i am taking only about files . You can check this for better understanding - https://pastebin.com/VwW52E9m

Comment: I have fixed that part in my answer. We need to pass a dummy string as `$0` in `bash -c` arguments.

Comment: `echo` is not pure bash; use `printf`, instead. ;)